# running ASP.NET Core project from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project called Foo.  It was generated using swagger-codegen from a Swagger API definition.  It builds and runs from the command line.  Visual Studio 2017 builds it but I cannot figure out how to get VS to use the correct run command for F5.  The VS build is working because the command line run command can still run it after building only in VS (and making a visible change in behavior to make sure that what VS built is what is running).  The command line run command is:

```
dotnet run -p Foo.csproj --launch-profile web
```

How can I (if it's possible) get VS to use this command or something equivalent to run it with F5?  That would be more convenient.  It would also allow (presumably) running it under the VS debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to test the scenario at this time, but you could try in your menu bar press "Debug", navigate to "Foo Properties..." go to the "Debug" tab on the left hand side you can setup your configuration there. From what I can remember launching "Project" will automatically perform `dotnet run -p Foo.csproj` and you can pass your arguments as required.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  Also allows running under the debugger, setting (and stopping at) a breakpoint, etc.